# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException in decrypt method using Base64

Tags: java, security, encryption

I am encrypting and decrypting a password with below the code.

```
public static String encrypt(String data, Key key) throws Exception {

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes());
    byte[] base64Bytes = Base64.encodeBase64(encryptedBytes);
    String base64EncodedString = new String(base64Bytes);
    return base64EncodedString;
}

public static String decrypt(String encrypted, Key key) throws Exception {

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(encrypted.getBytes());
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(decoded);
    return new String(decrypted);
}
```

Encryption is working fine. The exception is throwing at **doFinal** method of **decrypt** method.

Exception :

> [4/4/14 12:36:59:522 CDT] 00000024 SystemErr     R Caused by:
>   **javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Not PKCS#1 block type 2 or Zero padding** [4/4/14 12:36:59:523 CDT] 00000024 SystemErr     R      at
>   com.ibm.crypto.provider.RSA.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source) [4/4/14
>   12:36:59:523 CDT] 00000024 SystemErr     R      at
>   javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Unknown Source) [4/4/14 12:36:59:523 CDT]
>   00000024 SystemErr     R      at
>   com.moneygram.webpoe.util.SecurityProvider.decrypt(SecurityProvider.java:171)
>   [4/4/14 12:36:59:524 CDT] 00000024 SystemErr     R      at
>   com.moneygram.webpoe.util.SecurityProvider.decrypt(SecurityProvider.java:137)

Please help me if anybody has any resolution to this? I can provide if this is an incomplete information. I am stuck with this!!!

Comment: Oh, forgot to welcome you. Welcome to stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your issue, but I do know that you rely too much on defaults - for the keys, the character sets and the mode of encryption + padding mode.

Try the following and please indicate if this solves your problems:

```
public static String encrypt(String data, RSAPublicKey key) throws Exception {

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    return Base64.encodeBase64String(encryptedBytes);
}

public static String decrypt(String encrypted, RSAPrivateKey key) throws Exception {

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(encrypted);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(decoded);
    return new String(decrypted, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

Comment: looks like it is fixed. I am still testing on this.

Comment: are u fixing the issue..?if yes please mention your what's that error.?thanks for looking my comment.